# How do you access an app on Google Play Store for Internal Testing? (not alpha/closed/open tests)

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an app and trying to test it with a few people internally. I've added them to my list of testers and my Google Play Console App Dashboard says:

"Internal Testing: Active - 0 testers - Not reviewed"

The Internal testing page has my 1.0.0 release listed under Releases with a green check-mark: "Available to internal testers."

The Testers tab says "Testers can join your test on the web [copy link]." Sending the link to my testers opens an opt-in page, and after opting in it presents them with a Play Store link.

**Tapping the Play Store link opens the Play store which just sits and spins, as if it's loading something, forever.**

**From my app dashboard, clicking Google's "View on Google Play" link lands me on a "Not Found" page.**

What is up with this workflow? I can't tell if there's something I'm supposed to be doing, or if I should just wait a few days, or what. There's no error message. There's no guidance on the Google Play Console about what I should expect.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the answer is: just wait several days.

I'm appalled at the UX of infinite spinners with no explanation for 48+ hours, but there it is.